# Can you use templates in Next.js?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I am fairly new to web development and currently have a rudimentary web server using Node.js, Express, and Pug which I am hoping to convert to Next.js. Is it possible to create re-usable templates (similar to Pug/Jade) in Next.js?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do mine. There are better ways, but it's how I like it. I came from express handlebars, and have used pug before, so this is how I did mine.

In pages/_app.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const Layout = Component.Layout || LayoutEmpty // if page has no layout, it uses blank layout
  const PageTitle = Component.PageTitle // page title of the page

  return (
    <Layout>
      {PageTitle? (<Head><title>{PageTitle}</title></Head>) : '' }
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}

const LayoutEmpty = ({children}) => <>{children}</> // blank layout if doesnt detect any layout
```

In your component folder where ever you want to put your layout file: eg component/layout.js

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

export function LayoutOne({children}) {
try {
  return (<>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><Link href="/"><a>Home</a></Link></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>{children}</div>
  </>)
} catch(e) {console.log(e)}
}
```

Then in your pages: eg pages/about.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {LayoutOne} from '../component/layout' // location of your layout.js file

Aboutpage.PageTitle = 'About | Website Tag Line' // set title of your page
Aboutpage.Layout = LayoutOne // using LayoutOne. If you dont do this, its considered blank layout and you'll get no layout
export default function Aboutpage() {
try {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h2>About</h2>
      </div>
    </>
  );
} catch(e) {console.log(e)}
}
```

If you want more layout, in your layout.js file at the end, just change the name of the export function eg: LayoutTwo

```
export function LayoutTwo({children}) {
try {
  return (<>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><Link href="/dashboard"><a>Dashboard</a></Link></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>{children}</div>
  </>)
} catch(e) {console.log(e)}
}
```

And one the page, you change layout to two

```
import {LayoutTwo} from '../component/layout'
Aboutpage.Layout = LayoutTwo
```